# Реализация прыжка JS canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, разработка-игр

Решил попрактиковаться в написании небольшой игрушки на JS (canvas), но вот проблема: **при вызове прыжка игрок проходит лишь часть траектории и зависает в полете**, при зажатии клавиши все работает и игрок проходит по заданному пути. С чем это может быть связано?

```
'use strict';
//Canvas
let cvs = document.getElementById('canvas');
let ctx = cvs.getContext('2d');

//Height of window
let w = window.innerWidth -10;
let h = window.innerHeight -10;
cvs.width = w;
cvs.height = h;


//directions

let left = false;
let right = false;
let jump = false;



//blocks settings

let blockSize = 10;
let WorldGrowHeight = ~~(h/2/blockSize);

let WorldSize = 500;
let blockBorder = 0;
let WorldDepth = ~~(h /2/ blockSize) + blockSize;


let GameMap = [];


//user setttings
let userWidth = 25;
let userHeght = 50;
let userColor = "#ff0000";
let userPosX = w/2;
let userPosY = ~~(h/2.348);

let jumpCount = 0;
let jumpLength = 40;
let jumpHeight = 0;


//create game map
for (let y=WorldGrowHeight; y<=WorldDepth+WorldGrowHeight; y++) {
    for (let x = 0; x < WorldSize; x++) {
        let block = Math.floor(Math.random() * (3 - 1 + 1)) + 1;
        GameMap.push({x, y, type: block});
    }
}
//create user
let user = {
    width : userWidth,
    height : userHeght,
    posX : userPosX,
    posY: userPosY,
    color: userColor,

    image: function () {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.fillStyle = "#FF0000";
        ctx.rect(this.posX, this.posY-jumpHeight,  this.width, this.height);
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.closePath();

    },
    jump : function () {
            jumpCount++;
            jumpHeight = 4 * jumpLength * Math.sin(Math.PI * jumpCount / jumpLength);

        if (jumpCount > jumpLength) {
            jumpHeight = 0;
            jump = false;
            jumpCount = 0;
        }
    },
    update : function () {
        this.image();
        if (jump) {
            this.jump();
        }
    }
}
//Events
document.addEventListener('keydown', handlerUp, false);
document.addEventListener('keyup', handlerDown, false);
//Events Handlers
function handlerUp(e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 37) left = true;
    if (e.keyCode === 38) jump = true;
    if (e.keyCode === 39) right = true;
}
function handlerDown(e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 37) left = false;
    if (e.keyCode === 38) jump = false;
    if (e.keyCode === 39) right = false;
};

//Draw blocks by map
function drawMap() {
    GameMap.forEach(block => {
        switch (block.type) {
            case 1:
                ctx.fillStyle = "#2d190d";
                ctx.fillRect(block.x * (blockSize + blockBorder), block.y * (blockSize + blockBorder), blockSize, blockSize);
                break;
            case 2:
                ctx.fillStyle = "#1a2ebd";
                ctx.fillRect(block.x * (blockSize + blockBorder), block.y * (blockSize + blockBorder), blockSize, blockSize);
                break;
            case 3:
                ctx.fillStyle = "#2cbd19";
                ctx.fillRect(block.x * (blockSize + blockBorder), block.y * (blockSize + blockBorder), blockSize, blockSize);
                break;
        }
    });
}
//Update display

function update() {
    ctx.clearRect(0,0, w, h);
    drawMap();
    user.update();
}
//Frame Rate
setInterval(update, 1000/60);
console.log(GameMap);
```

Comment: отпускаете кнопку прыжка - `jump = false`, соответственно функция `jump` не вызывается

Comment: Спасибо, это помогло. Это было глупое упущение с моей стороны))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Спасибо **hu-fo**, ошибка действительно заключалось в этом:

> отпускаете кнопку прыжка - jump = false, соответственно функция jump не вызывается